Does an empty string allocate when converted to a Box<str>?
I'm using a message passing architecture for my app. One type that's commonly passed around is io::Result<Box<str>>. Sometimes, I want to pass around an empty string. Does any allocation occur when doing this?
fn pass_empty_string(tx: mpsc::Sender<io::Result<Box<str>>>) {
   tx.send(Ok("".into())) 
}


No. The control flow passes through few functions, but eventually it reaches RawVec::allocate_in(), which has the following check:
// Don't allocate here because `Drop` will not deallocate when `capacity` is 0.
if T::IS_ZST || capacity == 0 {
    Self::new_in(alloc)
}

If the string is a constant, LLVM will also optimize the code away.
However, note that this is not guaranteed.

The benchmarking library divan has an allocation tracker that can help us answer this question. In benches/alloc_test.rs:
fn main() {
    divan::main();
}

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: divan::AllocProfiler = divan::AllocProfiler::system();

#[divan::bench]
fn allocates() -> String {
    String::from("hello")
}

#[divan::bench]
fn maybe_allocates() -> Box<str> {
    "".into()
}

Then, when we run the benchmark...
$ cargo bench

     Running benches/alloc_test.rs
Timer precision: 12 ns
parser              fastest       │ slowest       │ median        │ mean          │ samples │ iters
├─ allocates        4.918 ns      │ 25.84 ns      │ 5.168 ns      │ 7.119 ns      │ 100     │ 6400
│                   alloc:        │               │               │               │         │
│                     1           │ 1             │ 1             │ 1             │         │
│                     5 B         │ 5 B           │ 5 B           │ 5 B           │         │
╰─ maybe_allocates  0.233 ns      │ 3.125 ns      │ 0.239 ns      │ 0.277 ns      │ 100     │ 102400

... we see that it does not!

I find the approach a bit round-about for such a simple question... but wow how nice that is for more complex scenarios!
